# Smooth scroll in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery

I use this code for smooth scroll:

```js
if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, {passive: false} );
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;

function wheel(event) {
  var delta = 0;
  if (event.wheelDelta) delta = event.wheelDelta / 120;
  else if (event.detail) delta = -event.detail / 3;

  handle(delta);
  if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
}

var goUp = true;
var end = null;
var interval = null;

function handle(delta) {
  var animationInterval = 20; //lower is faster
  var scrollSpeed = 20; //lower is faster

  if (end == null) {
    end = $(window).scrollTop();
  }
  end -= 20 * delta;
  goUp = delta > 0;

  if (interval == null) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var step = Math.round((end - scrollTop) / scrollSpeed);
      if (scrollTop <= 0 || 
          scrollTop >= $(window).prop("scrollHeight") - $(window).height() ||
          goUp && step > -1 || 
          !goUp && step < 1 ) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        end = null;
      }
      $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop + step );
    }, animationInterval);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>

  
  <main>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem repellat, fugiat iusto nam debitis magnam temporibus! Eius harum commodi ut suscipit veritatis accusantium ex at, vitae. Possimus deserunt totam perferendis veniam maiores nihil! Doloremque aliquam voluptate aperiam, eos nulla dolor?
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique molestiae cupiditate obcaecati consectetur dolor facilis quod consequuntur est cumque pariatur sed sint neque hic magni aliquid, cum placeat blanditiis! Ab cupiditate harum placeat, esse quaerat neque! Nam est excepturi, ab accusamus provident error, beatae mollitia rem deserunt architecto earum quos. Magnam animi harum perspiciatis autem id vitae doloremque, ducimus est fugit illum aspernatur tempora temporibus at esse voluptate possimus deserunt nesciunt corrupti mollitia odit, veniam architecto. Ea, consequatur, enim. Facilis ipsam numquam cum earum molestias, ab sequi reiciendis distinctio necessitatibus illum! Laborum error autem repudiandae rerum cum, dicta voluptatibus! Itaque.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae dolore eum molestias possimus dolor voluptatibus aliquid nobis quia dolorum nulla!
    </p>
  </main>
```

Smooth scrolling, everywhere works and worked in chrome until recently.

Now start to get out the error:

> [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener
>   due to target being treated as passive. See

And smooth scrolling in chrome does not work.

**Question:** What is the error and how to solve the problem of smooth scrolling in google chrome for this code?

Comment: Personal opinion here, but I'm glad Chrome disables this effect. It's awful. It only serves to stop me scrolling quickly down the page. It's one of those stylistic effects which has a detrimental effect on the UX. I'd suggest considering removing it for the sanity of your users

Comment: It seems to be caused by the fact that you're using inline event listeners, for which you can't set the passive option to `false`. If the second line is changed to `window.addEventListener('wheel', wheel, {passive: false});` the message disappears. Your script was still working for me on Chrome though, despite the prevention of default actions getting ignored (which is what `passive: true`) does. I recommend putting feature detection for passive listeners in place, quite a few browsers will likely not support that third event listener option so the script will crash there.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the smooth scroll [plugin](https://codepen.io/Shikkediel/pen/GJRbOV) I wrote a while back (and now adapted for this issue), it uses `requestAnimationFrame` on `window` to scroll and has about the same default characteristic as Firefox smooth scrolling (but it's all customisable). I think it's a lot more user friendly than this, which seems to hold back scrolling progress a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a modified version of smoothscroll.js with {passive:false} in a couple of areas to prevent the error:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a simple fix. I have not checked which one are needed for this case but it fixed by changing lines 511-517 to

```
if (global.navigator.pointerEnabled) {
  crossvent[op](el, pointers[type], fn, { passive: false });
} else if (global.navigator.msPointerEnabled) {
 crossvent[op](el, microsoft[type], fn, { passive: false });
} else {
crossvent[op](el, touch[type], fn, { passive: false });
crossvent[op](el, type, fn, { passive: false });
}
```

See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080 and for details about the recent updates https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.

Hope this helps

Comment: You do need to consider about it aswell since they have updated it. Which means that it wont be the same as it was before easily smoothly browsing chrome

Comment: 'it fixed by changing lines 511-517 to'.. lines 511-517 of what? This doesn't appear relevant to the OP's logic

Comment: Are you able to share me the code so i can see what your code looks like compared to myne or what you can do is look at the website and change it there but it will be easier if you can send me the code

Comment: It's not as simple a fix as the person you copied that from thinks it is because it has no feature check for the passive event listener, making the script crash for older browsers. Besides that, one won't always have access to the jQuery source code (this answer refers to that) so the best option at this moment (until they fix it) is to use plain event listeners in your own script.